# Changed from Socket to SSLSocket and reading returns error code 2

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am trying to change the communication of my app. It works with Sockets but I have to make it work using SSLSockets, so I did some changes and here is what I got.

```
String pemData = readPemFile();
pemData = pemData.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----","")
        .replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----","");
byte[] byteArray = android.util.Base64.decode(pemData, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(is);

String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("cert", cert);

String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

SSLSocketFactory tlsSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
sslSocket = (SSLSocket) tlsSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port);
sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2"});
```

Basically, I used the code from https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java and did changes in order to use the SSL Socket and to load the X.509 certificate (I only have the PEM file).

To send and read the socket, I used the same code I had but using the sslSocket instead:

```
inputStream = new DataInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream());
outputStream = new DataOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream());

LOG.info("trying to write ");

byte[] messageBytes = this.message.getBytes(Constans.FORMATO_TEXTO_TCPIP);
outputStream.write(messageBytes);
outputStream.flush();

LOG.info("Data sent to the socket " + this.message);
nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length);

if(nRead != -1) {
    /* ... */
}
```

When I run it, I got the folowing log:

```
D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 SSL_connect:3RFINA SSLv3 read finished A
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 info_callback ignored
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 info_callback where=0x20 ret=1
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 handshake done in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 info_callback calling handshakeCompleted
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 info_callback completed
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=1
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 SSL_connect:ok exit in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 info_callback ignored
D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=1
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 NativeCrypto_SSL_get_certificate => NULL
I/TcpConnectionThread: trying to write 
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 sslWrite buf=0x41476750 len=46 write_timeout_millis=0
D/NativeCrypto: Doing SSL_write() with 46 bytes to go ssl=0x52ab0830, appData=0x51810998
D/NativeCrypto: Returned from SSL_write() with result 46, error code 0 ssl=0x52ab0830, appData=0x51810998
I/TcpConnectionThread: Data sent to the socket //some special characters...
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x52ab0830 sslRead buf=0x4146dbe8 len=16384,timeo=40000
D/NativeCrypto: Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x52ab0830, appData=0x51810998
D/NativeCrypto: Returned from SSL_Read() with result -1, error code 2 ssl=0x52ab0830, appData=0x51810998
D/NativeCrypto: sslSelect type=READ fd=46 appData=0x51810998 timeout_millis=40000
```

Some facts:

- The server I used to the Socket is not the same I use to the SSLSocket
- I don't have access to the server code
- I don't have access to the server logs
- There are devices using the same certificate and they work

I would appreciate any help

Comment: does the Java code yield any exception or read error?

Comment: If the handshake completes, I'd say that rules out SSL as the problem. More likely something to do with the fact it's a different server.

Comment: i use this all the time: outputStream.write(byte[], offset, length)?

Comment: @nandsito no, the only information I have about the reading is in the log Returned from SSL_Read() with result -1, error code 2 as shown before.

Comment: @greeble31 Actually it is the same server but with different port, I don't know if it changes anything. The devices that work with the certificate work with the "SSL server"

Comment: @user1506104 just did it, but still doesn't work

Comment: before writing, can you check if socket is still connected?

Comment: @user1506104 I am doing it, I have this `(sslSocket != null && sslSocket.isConnected())`

Comment: Are you sure the client is actually sending the certificate you loaded? A .pcap could tell you that. I ask b/c it doesn't look to me like you provided a private key for that certificate, making it essentially unusable. Then the server (if it doesn't outright reject unauthenticated clients) may be rejecting the connection shortly after the handshake completes.

Comment: @greeble31 It seems to be the problem, I was checking it and in fact, I have not loaded any private key, I have already asked for a private key but I have to wait, thank you